# How do I plot a line chart 1 minute price data, omitting the straight lines when the market is closed overnight or at weekends

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a series of made up of 1 minute data, which contains a datetime and value.  The data contains values between 07:00 and 18:00 for Monday to Friday only

When I use MatPlotLib to plot a line chart, I get unsightly strait lines between 18:01 and 06:59, and over the weekend.

How do I create a plot that 'joins' all the 1 minute price points together, but omits the gaps overnight and at weekend, this giving a smooth continuous chart?

Edit: apologies, I'm not being clear. I wish to see a see a chart as if I had squeezed out the gaps, and have a continuous line based on my data points - and keep the x axis time stamps

```
s = a series of data

mask = (s.index.dayofweek < 5) & (s.index.hour >= 7) & (s.index.hour < 18)

# filter the series using the mask
filtered_prices = s[mask]

# create the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
ax.plot(filtered_prices.index, filtered_prices.values)

# set axis labels and title
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Price')
ax.set_title('Price Data for April 2023 (Weekdays 7am-6pm)')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've edited this answer to hopefully be what you're looking for:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

#Create example datetime date
dates = ['2023-04-10 07:00','2023-04-10 07:45','2023-04-10 09:00','2023-04-10 10:20','2023-04-10 12:00',
         '2023-04-10 12:50','2023-04-10 14:00','2023-04-10 15:10','2023-04-10 16:45','2023-04-10 18:00',
        '2023-04-11 07:20','2023-04-11 08:40','2023-04-11 10:00','2023-04-11 11:30']
a = [datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").date() for date in dates]

#Arbitrary y-value data
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]

plt.plot(range(len(a)),b) #Plot y data against 1->len(x) data (will make sure all data is connected)
plt.xticks(range(len(a)), a) #Change x-axis markers to reflect original x-axis data labels
plt.show()
```

So I created new mock data to better represent your problem with datetime x-values. The date consists of 10 values for today's date (within the working hours you've outlined) and 4 values for tomorrow's date
I've attached two images below, first one to show plotting without corrections and the second shows what my posted code above plots post corrections.
I hope this helps, if not let me know, I'm happy to help!

Without corrections:

[image]

After corrections (also added a rotation value to xticks to better display dates):

[image]

I'm not entirely sure on what your data looks like, but I would imagine the code you presented would have to be changed to look something like this:

```
s = a series of data

mask = (s.index.dayofweek < 5) & (s.index.hour >= 7) & (s.index.hour < 18)

# filter the series using the mask
filtered_prices = s[mask]

# create the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
ax.plot(range(len(filtered_prices.index)), filtered_prices.values)

# set axis labels and title
plt.xticks(range(len(filtered_prices.index)), filtered_prices.index, rotation='50')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Price')
ax.set_title('Price Data for April 2023 (Weekdays 7am-6pm)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work, and apologies, maybe my question wasn't clear enough (this is my first submission to SO).  

This removes the straight 'join' line, leaving a gap of empty space.  

What I actually want is a continuous line for just the available data... so, for example, it plots to 18:00 on Friday, and then continues to plot from 07:00 on Monday morning.

Comment: Hey @user21594319, no worries at all, I just misunderstood what you were looking for! I've edited my answer to hopefully be what you're looking for, if not just let me know.

Comment: So, does this mean that I will have to slice up my original dataframe into chunks, then splice them back together this way, in order to plot?  Seems a little.... messy?  (But.. if there is no other way.. it is what it is!)
It feels frustrating there isn't some standard/built in way to handle this?

Comment: No there's no need to break it up, I was just trying to add an extra set of values to my mock data that had a greater variance in x values. Let me update this example to make it closer/clearer to what you have.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That's very helpful: it helps me to understand a bit better how this works (an excruciating process for an old newbie like me).

Answer (score 0):

If you use pandas for the series its a easy fix.
you can try:

```
s.ffill()
```

This basically takes the last known value and fills it into all following NaNs until there is a real value again. This fills your chart over closing hours.

Comment: This just fills the gap with a horizontal line, which isn't what I want.  I want the chart to stop at 18:00 on Friday, and start again at 07:00 on monday, with now gap.